# JFrame: 'Random' size?

Tags: java, swing

I created a JFrame with a size of 400x400 pixels.

But every time I run my application, it has another size (410 x 410), and sometimes it has 400 x 400 pixels.

The code:

```
panel = new JPanel() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -620625052080099140L;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paint(graphics);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;
    }
};



panel.setSize(sizeX, sizeY);
panel.setDoubleBuffered(true);


frame= new JFrame("Simulation");

frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(panel);
frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sizeX, sizeY));
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Change the size after you call `.pack()`, then you'll have your fixed size.

Comment: What should I call? .setSize(...) or .getContentPane().setPrefferedSize(...)? Calling setSize() will include the borders of the window, this is different on all OSes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What should I call? .setSize(...) or .getContentPane().setPrefferedSize(...)?

You don't call any size method. It is the job of the layout manager to determine the size. The the pack() methjod will determine the proper sizes.

In order for the pack() method to work each component should return a preferred size. So because you are doing custom painting you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your class to return an appropriate Dimension for the panel.

Also, you should be overriding the `paintComponent()` method NOT the paint() method.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples of the above suggestions.

Comment: No, that does not help.But before that project I developed a game that uses the same methods. But they do not work too (at this project, but they work nice in the game), however. Now I have decided to paint everything directly into the JFrame, that works.

Comment: *"I have decided to paint everything directly into the JFrame"*  That is not the optimal approach.  But like I said, post an MCVE and I'll show you what I mean.

Comment: I have overridden the `getPreferredSize()` method in the JFrame, and that works. So, why is it actually not ok paint it directly into the JFrame?

Comment: You override the getPreferredSize() method of the panel where you do the custom painting, NOT The frame. Read the tutorial for a working example!!!

Comment: Ok, I have overridden the `getPreferredSize()` method now in the panel AND the frame. Now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The custom painted panel should return a sensible preferred size to show the custom rendering.

Pack the panel and you'll find it reduces to the minimum size needed to display the content, as well as the size of the frame decorations.  Exactly as big as it needs to be in order to show the content and decorations.

Comment: You mean calling .pack() on a panel? No, there is no such method. But the problem also occurs when showing an empty frame, without any components (JPanel in this case) added.

Comment: No, I meant call `pack()` on the `JFrame` **after** overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method of the custom painted **`JPanel`**.  Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) & I'll explain in code.

Comment: @Ercksen: _Sometimes_ always makes me think of [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).